# error: only position independent executables (PIE) are supported when I try to run curl on android 5.1

Tags: applications, android-versions, 5.1-lollipop

I'm trying to run curl on android 5.1,but this error doesn't help :

```
root@manta:/root/home/curl/data/local/bin # ./curl
error: only position independent executables (PIE) are supported.
```

I've got the curl executable from here :

```
http://curl.haxx.se/
```

how can I fix this error ? thanks.

Comment: Bypassing the new `PIE security` check : http://forum.xda-developers.com/google-nexus-5/development/fix-bypassing-pie-security-check-t2797731 maybe can help.

Comment: I have tried,but it didn't work. Android said that a lot of applications have stopped working.

Comment: @LinX64: I flashed that thing, and got a boot loop (CY12, Android 5.0.2, Galaxy Tab 8.4). I had to flash CY12 back again.

Answer (score 1):

Curl is an open source project, so the straightforward answer is that you compile it yourself and enable position independent code (pic) for the compilation. This is very inconvenient, I admit, but I strongly discourage using solutions that disable security features. There are good reasons to only allow PIEs.